# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found for Bigquery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-oauth, .net-4.5

I'm using Google BigQuery to transfer data from file to BigQuery. I'm using BigQuery Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 version="1.3.0" and it's dependent dlls. My C# code works fine in ConsoleApplication VS2019 but when I'm using SSIS task, I'm getting the error:

> *System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential Google.Api.Gax.Rest.ScopedCredentialProvider.GetCredentials(Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential)'.
>      at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient.Create(String projectId, GoogleCredential credential)*

```
var googlecredential = new GoogleCredentials()
                {
                    private_key = "",
                    client_email = "",
                    type = ""
                };
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(googlecredential));
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credentials); -> this line throws error if I'm referencing dll Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 version 1.3 or 1.4 and it works if for 1.2 version.
```

Note: This error is only happening in script task. All the Dlls are registered in GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally I've solved it by using BigqueryService instead of BigQueryClient.

```
var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "CS Bigquery"
            });
```

Full sample I've used is here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/785554/Google-BigQuery-API-Client-Sample-Code-for-Csharp